# MySQL Select statement containing Group By is returning single record hits

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table that contains a list of files and their sizes, and my goal is to select out only those files where the filename and size are equal. So I came up with this Select statement:

```
SELECT FileName, FileSize FROM Files WHERE FileName IN 
    (
    SELECT FileName FROM Files WHERE FileSize > 10240 
    GROUP BY FileName, FileSize HAVING Count(*) > 1
    )
ORDER BY FileName, FileSize;
```

The problem is, as I was sifting through the results, I saw these records:

```
022704.jpg  40960
022704.jpg  42080
022704.jpg  42080
022704.jpg  42080
022704.jpg  42080
```

Wher the top record has a size different than the rest. So I ran this query

```
SELECT FileName, FileSize from Files WHERE FileName = '022704.jpg' AND FileSize = 40960;
```

And sure enough, there is only one record with that filename and that file size.

What am I doing wrong in my first select statement?

Edit:

I see what I'm doing wrong now - The query will return the record as long as the filename is in the subquery without respecting the subquery in the final results ... but I don't know how to fix it. When I modified the query to look like this

```
SELECT FileName, FileSize FROM Files WHERE FileName IN 
    (
    SELECT FileName FROM Files WHERE FileSize > 10024 
    GROUP BY FileName, FileSize HAVING Count(*) > 1
    )
AND FileSize in 
    (
    SELECT FileSize FROM Files WHERE FileSize > 10024 
    GROUP BY FileName, FileSize HAVING Count(*) > 1
    )
ORDER BY FileName, FileSize;
```

The query is still running after 5 minutes of waiting.

Comment: You're grabbing all rows associated with those file names, not just the rows having the corresponding size too.  You need something like `SELECT ... WHERE (filename, size) IN (SELECT filename, size FROM ... GROUP BY filename, size HAVING ...) AS xxx ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 1):

Size needs to be part of the `IN` logic as well.  Try this:

```
SELECT FileName, FileSize
  FROM Files WHERE (FileName, FileSize) IN 
    (
      SELECT FileName, FileSize FROM Files WHERE FileSize > 10240 
       GROUP BY FileName, FileSize HAVING Count(*) > 1
    )
ORDER BY FileName, FileSize
;
```

For the performance issue, make sure you have an index on `(FileName, FileSize)`.

Comment: OK, so I put an INDEX type index on FileSize and FULLTEXT index on FileName, then I truncated the table and re-populated it and it seems to me that your query does the same as mine does (in the edit of my post) - I've let yours run now for 2 hours and it still hasn't completed.

Comment: @MichaelSims That's because you didn't provide the types of your columns.  With normal types that can be indexed together, you would create a composite index on the pair `(FileName, FileSize)`. Are you sure FileName can't be adjusted for this purpose?  Does the calculation need to be exact?  Maybe you could index the prefix or hash of FileName and use that in your logic.

Comment: Well, in this use case, I'm using the data to find exact matches where the filename and the file size are exactly the same, and when I employ the final application, there will be millions of records that I will need to search.